# VS Code PHP Intelephense objects in array not showing properties and functions to -> operator

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am new to VS Code, so I don't know what's happening here.
I have a fresh Intelephense installation, and have disabled basic PHP suggestions, but when I type out an array, in which are objects, after I type the -> operator, the object properties and functions don't show up in the recommendations.

Is there a way to make it work?

Example:

```
class newClass {
  public $property1;
  public $property2;
  public function NewFunction {
    return 'Something';
  }
}
$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ {
  $temp = new newClass;
  $temp -> property2 = 'SomeData';
  $array[$i] = $temp;
  $array[$i] -> property1 = 'Random';
  unset($temp);
}
```

EDIT: So this is how I read in an array full of objects. Problem is, when I type in the $array[$i] -> property1 = 'Random' line, it doesn't give the recommendation.

When I type the last row, after I type the -> operator, I would expect Intelephense to list all the properties and functions of class newClass. But it doesn't. 
Also, I'm using normal array because objectArray doesn't support foreach according to official manual. Therefore, to me, is useless.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Did you forget the dollars? Are you creating a variable with the same name as a built-in function?

Comment: oh yep, in the class. woops. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation on arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key [of an array] can either be an int or a string. The value can be of any type.

So, for example, we can have:

```php
$obj1 = new MyClass;
$my_array[0] = $obj1;
```

But, since the values stored in an array can be of *any* type, there's nothing stopping us from then doing something like, say:

```php
$my_array[1] = "hello";
$my_array[2] = 5;
```

This makes it pretty difficult for an editor to infer that `$my_array[0]` contains a (pointer to) an object of type `MyClass`.

However, since you already have `$obj1` pointing to such an instance, the editor should be able to give pretty good suggestions after you've typed in `$obj1->`. Then, since `$obj1` and `$my_array[0]` point to the *same object*, any edits made via `$obj1` would affect the object `$my_array[0]` is pointing to.

With only *PHP Intelephense* active, VS Code gives the following suggestions:

[image: screenshot showing suggestions]

So:

```php
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public $property1;
    public $property2;
}

$obj1 = new MyClass;
$my_array[0] = $obj1;
$obj1->property1 = "Random";
$obj1->property2 = "Another";
echo $my_array[0]->property1 . "<br>" . $my_array[0]->property2;
```

will give us these settings, even though they were set via (pointer) `$obj1` and displayed via (pointer) `$my_array[0]`.

Having said that, we can use *DocBlock* type hinting to let the editor know our intentions. For example, if we have:

```php
/** @var MyClass[] */
$my_array[0] = $obj1;
```

then the editor can provide useful suggestions on the array too:

[image: code completion on array]

For more information, see [this *phpDocumentor* page on *DocBlocks*](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/what-is-a-docblock.html).

Comment: Yes, it SHOULD be able to suggest this, but it doesn't. Just how do I make it so that Intelephense extension does give me those suggestions? :D

Comment: Strange — it works on my end. I've added a screenshot to my post so you can see what I get. I don't remember fiddling around with the default settings too much.

Comment: Oh that. Well that does nothing, because I have an array of objects, and the original objects are long gone, since they were set using a for loop, and they were unset as the last line in the for loop.
So ofc it gives recommendations for individual and isolated objects, but the problem is, that referring to them as $my_array[0]-> doesn't. So I updated my original post to reflect what I mean even better.

Comment: Dear Lord! I see your edit and raise you one edit!

Comment: Ahh okay, made it work. Thank you very much, I had no idea about this hinting. These editor phrases like hinting and linting meant nothing to me, and now that I googled it, I still can't really find a proper source for reading about it, for syntax, but with that line @var line, it works.
So for the future, can you tell me what the syntax is for any type of variable? Or link a page where it's properly explained pls? :)

Comment: No problem. :) I've added a link to the post. Enjoy!